# How to show all month from 2 dates using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a variable called `$conn_date` which value is `2016-09-18`.

Now I want to show all months from `2016-09-18` to **till** now. But using bellow php code I can't get current month.

```
$begin = new DateTime($conn_date); // value is : 2016-09-18
$end = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d") );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 Month');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$ok = array();
foreach ( $period as $k=>$dt ) {  
    if ( $dt->format("Y-m-d") ) {        
        $ok[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ok);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-09-18
    [1] => 2016-10-18
    [2] => 2016-11-18
    [3] => 2016-12-18
)
```

I want to show current months too, How can I do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "current months"?

Comment: `new DateTime( date("Y-m-d") )` can be replaced with `new DateTime()`. Do **not** mix procedural and object-oriented functions.

Comment: @BizzyBob "current months" means "2017-17-01"

Comment: so your desired output is: Array
(
    [0] => 2016-09-18
    [1] => 2016-10-18
    [2] => 2016-11-18
    [3] => 2016-12-18
    [4] => 2017-01-18
)

Comment: Iterate from the current date as far back as you want to go subtracting by 1 month.

Comment: what you want to be in the last index is the date today?

Comment: `$ok[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");` to `$ok[] = $dt->format("m");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$begin = new DateTime($conn_date); // value is : 2016-09-18
$end = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d") );
$end->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 Month');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$ok = array();
foreach ( $period as $k=>$dt ) {  
    if ( $dt->format("Y-m-d") ) {        
        $ok[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ok);
echo '</pre>';
```

//Here "P1M" is a one-month duration, Visit http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "2007-01-01";
$b = "2008-02-15";

$i = date("Ym", strtotime($a));
while($i <= date("Ym", strtotime($b))){
    echo $i."\n";
    if(substr($i, 4, 2) == "12")
        $i = (date("Y", strtotime($i."01")) + 1)."01";
    else
        $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one interval to your end date.  In your case `$end->modify('1 month')`

So the full code:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-09-18');
$end = new DateTime();

$unitQty = '1 month';
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($unitQty);
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end->modify($unitQty));

$ok = array();
foreach ( $period as $k=>$dt ) {
    if ( $dt->format("Y-m-d") ) {
        $ok[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    }
}
```